# What system do websites like Graphy & Wordpress use to connect domains and not reveal their code?

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, hosting

I was wondering how these websites work, like they give you nameservers and you can connect them to your domain. Then, when you access your domain, you get their site and admin panel. You don't have to get hosting. The best part is, this way, they never reveal their core source code.

Good examples are Wordpress.com and graphy.com. I have been wondering what system do they use? Is there any documentation for such a system or what is it called?

Pardon me, I would have googled, but, I couldn't even think of good search terms to look for this. And, the ones I tried showed irrelevant results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The broad concept is Software as a Service (SaaS). You just sign up for an account, and get to use the software. You don't need access to the underlying hosting infrastructure, because everything is done for you. Sometimes the provider might actually provision you a whole set of infrastructure just for your instance of the application, or sometimes you might be on shared infrastructure but with a domain/subdomain which points to a folder on their webserver holding your copy of the software. There are many ways to do it, but now you know it's SaaS you can research it a lot easier yourself

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot for the reply. This could exactly be what I was looking for. Appreciate it. Just confirming. I have a website at mysite.com which hosts a script. Using SaaS, another member with a domain hisite.com could connect to mine but not get access to my source code?

BTW, is coolify.io a good option for that?

Comment: I didn't know coolify before but from a brief glance it looks like a good tool maybe, but not sure it provides a whole SaaS infrastructure by itself. And attaching another domain to your hosted site is not by itself SaaS either - many hosting companies will let you associate multiple domains with your site already. SaaS is a bit more complicated. I strongly suggest doing a lot more research and reading, before you ask anything too in-depth or start looking at specific tools. Otherwise you will be totally out of your depth

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

> The best part is, this way, they never reveal their core source code.

There isn't any special mechanism for this, it's *literally* just a "someone else's website".

To start with, there is **no relation** between "Connecting to your domain" and "revealing code". When you publish a website, you don't have to upload the website's code to the domain itself as part of the "domain connection" – the domain isn't what serves the site or app. The domain only points to a web server by IP address, and it's the web server that holds the code (and the code runs on the server itself).

So there is really nothing more to it than pointing your domain to *someone else's* web server instead of your own (and having their web server be configured to recognize it, just as you would configure yours). You could get a domain, point it at your friend's personal webserver, and they could host an app for you without having to reveal anything about it to you.

As a more realistic example, when your web hosting company sets up your hosting account and gives you FTP access, they could just as easily *not* give you FTP access and instead deploy a webapp template and only give you admin access to that webapp. (That's actually something that web hosting companies offer; often they have a plan where they'll set up a copy of the installable WordPress or some other webapp for you.)

What WordPress.com does is practically the same; it's just that they're both the hosting provider *and* the software vendor at the same time. (And they've altered their software to allow a single instance of the webapp to recognize everyone's domains instead of needing one copy for each user; this would be called 'multi-tenancy'.)

("SaaS" is the term for the *general practice* of offering access to such websites – it is *not* a particular technology that you "use" to achieve this; rather, it's what the *result* is called.)

> You don't have to get hosting

It's true that *you* don't have to get hosting, but that's only because Wordpress hosts it for you. So in a sense you do get hosting, it's just 100% managed by Wordpress and set up behind the scenes.